# Proving that a group homomorphism preserves the identity element

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Assume that $(G,*)$ and $(H,o)$ are groups and that $f:(G,*) \rightarrow (H,o)$ is a homomorphism.

> Let $e_G$ and $e_H$ denote the identity elements of $G$ and $H$, respectively. Show that $f(e_G)=e_H$.

Approach: $f(e_G)=f(a*a^{-1})$ for $a,a^{-1} \in G$,
so $f(a*a^{-1})=f(a)of(a^{-1})$.

If that’s true, then how do we know that  $f(a^{-1})$ is the inverse of $f(a)$?

Comment: You don't, that would require $f(e)=e$.  But try your same argument but with $a=e$ and it will work, we know $e^{-1}=e$ right.

Comment: I think you can carry on with $f(a)f(a^{-1}) = f(a)f(a)^{-1} = e_H$. If you are allowed to use $f(a^{-1}) = f(a)^{-1}$

Comment: @Nameless, that's what I have to prove next

Comment: @TheMathNoob, well I guess you can't use what I suggested. You need help with that one or...?

Comment: Yes, please...... how to show that $f(a^{-1})=f(a)^{-1}$

Comment: @TheMathNoob, well actually we can more or less use what did here. Since you know $f(a)f(a^{-1}) = e_H$, what must $f(a^{-1})$ be? Actually I think my initial comment was backwards.

Comment: Right that's what I was thinking. We already showed $f(a) \circ f(a^{-1})=e_H$, so we can conclude $f(a)$ is the inverse of $f(a^{-1})$ and $f(a^{-1})$ is the inverse of $f(a)$

Comment: I don't understand what $F$ is. Is it $f$?

Comment: where? what F?.

Comment: @TheMathNoob: In the second line, "...Show that $F(e_G)=e_H$."

Comment: sorry, it's $f$

Comment: Aside: Note that $f(e) = e$ and $f(a^{-1})=f(a)^{-1}$ are important parts of what it means to be a homomorphism -- what you're proving is that the simplified definition (only requires that it preserves the product) actually implies these additional aspects. The simplified definition is a little misleading to the general intuition about homomorphisms of other kinds of structure.

Comment: In particular, if you have a monoid (group without inverses), a function that preserves the operation need not preserve the identity element – e.g. non-negative integers form a monoid under $\max$ with identity $0$, and $+ k$ preserves $\max$, but it doesn't preserve $0$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using the fact that $e_G\ast e_G=e_G$ yields
$$ f(e_G)=f(e_G\ast e_G)=f(e_G)\circ f(e_G)$$

Now multiply both sides by the inverse of $f(e_G)$ to obtain $f(e_G)=e_H$.

Comment: ok so $f(e_G)=f(e_G) \circ f(e_G)$, $f(e_G) \circ  f^{-1}(e_G)=(f(e_G)\circ f(e_G)) \circ f^{-1}(e_G)$ and hence $\circ $ is associative we can say $f(e_G)=e_H$

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: That trick seemed to be very useless XD.

Comment: In other words: An element of a group is idempotent iff it is the neutral element. It is immediate that $f(e_G)$ is idempotent.

Answer (score 8):

The answers provided here are excellent, but here is something to just widen your mind for diversity.

So if $a\in G$ $$f(a) = f(a* e_G) = f(a)\circ f(e_G).$$

Left cancel by $f(a)^{-1}$ to get $e_H$

Comment: Oh woahhh XDDDDD

Answer (score 4):

We have $e_G = e_G \ast e_G$, then

$$f(e_G) = f(e_g \ast e_G) = f(e_G)\circ f(e_G).$$

Now, $$e_H = [f(e_G)]^{-1}\circ f(e_G) = [f(e_G)]^{-1}\circ (f(e_G)f(e_G)) = f(e_G).$$